# Wowza, iOS and HTML5 video tag

Tags: streaming, html5-video, wowza

I'm trying to use the  tag from html5 to stream to an ipad... It's supposed to be as simple as setting up the video tag with the right source and that's all, but this is not working at all...

I found on this page http://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html a link to a sample, an rtsp url, the one I have to use for iOS devices...

I'm doing this:

```
<video controls="controls" >
    <source src="rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov" />
</video>
```

And I also tried with

```
<video controls="controls" src="src="rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov"></video>
```

But neither of them, on the webpage I just get a black box with a "Play" button crossed, and of course it doesn't work....

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using like below for HTML5 streaming from Wowza on Amazon EC2

```
http://[VIDEO_PATH]:1935/vod/mp4:videoclip1/playlist.m3u8
```

Replace the video path with your ip and video clip with your video name

Comment: its working on only safari on ipad and in iphone., it don't run on chrome and in windows safari.