# HTML5 Multi-platform player with one Wowza stream

Tags: html, rtmp, wowza, transcoding

**GOAL**

FLV Video files being served by Wowza Media Server to be played on all devices, platform/browser independent.  I'm currently working with a player loaded with AJAX which uses VideoJS.

**WHERE IM WORKING**

http://activemd.net/html5/

**THE CODE**

It seems like you have to provide 3 different types of videos for HTML5, so my approach is trying to have Wowza transcode them to the 3 types.

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="" preload="none" width="432" height="300" poster="amd-poster.jpg" autoplay="" data-setup="{}">
<source src="http://74.208.104.107:1935/riverview/mp4:ri_martino.flv" type="video/mp4">
<source src="http://74.208.104.107:1935/riverview/webm:ri_martino.flv" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://74.208.104.107:1935/riverview/ogg:ri_martino.flv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

**PROBLEM**

My videos won't play, anywhere.  When I use http versions of the videos, my player plays them without a problem.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

An example from the StackOverflow post at: [Wowza, iOS and HTML5 video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355296/wowza-ios-and-html5-video-tag)

An example from the Wowza post at: http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?35-How-to-set-up-video-on-demand-streaming

**QUESTION**

How can I get my FLV videos to be streamed to all devices, regardless of platform or browser?

Am I going about the whole transcoding approach incorrectly?

Thanks.
Rick

Comment: You wull need to convert the flv videos to mp4 format, so far that I know the transcoding only work for live streaming

Comment: Did you get this working?  We are in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

WebM & Ogg are not supported for Video On Demand (VOD) application. You must convert the file to MP4.
You can also use JW Player which is a Wowza supported player.